# Unable to add value to a java generic list

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

Here's my sample code:

```
public class MyList<T extends Number> {

  private List<T> items;

  public void func() {
    items.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
  }
}
```

I think I should be able to add integer to items, but compilation fails:

```
Required type: T
Provided: Integer
```

Anyone knows what's wrong here?

Comment: Your List is not instantiated. Note that when you instantiate it, you'll have to do so with a concrete parameter, not `<T>`. `func()` should receive the value that you want to store in your List as a parameter: `func(T value)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider a more complete version of your example:

```
public class MyList<T extends Number> {

    private List<T> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void func() {
        items.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
    }
}
```

Suppose *for the sake of argument* that the compiler says that is OK.

And now we will create an instance and call the `func` method:

```
MyList<Double> myDoubles = new MyList<>();
myDoubles.func();
```

Here is what happens.

1. We create a `MyList` instance where `T` is `Double`.  That's OK: the `Double` class implements the `Number` interface.
2. The `items` has a notional type of `List<Double>` and we initialize it with an `ArrayList`.  So we now have a list what should only contain `Double` values.
3. In the call to `func` we attempt to add an `Integer` to the `List<Double>`.  That is wrong!

That is what the compilation error is saying with the `Required type: T Provided: Integer` message.

To spell it out, the compiler expects a value whose type is the type that `T` is going to be at runtime.  But you have given it `Integer`.  While `Integer` implements the `Number` interface, it is not necessary the same as what `T` will be at runtime.  That is the root cause of your compilation error.

---

So what is the solution?

Well it depends on what the (actual) problem that this example is intended to solve.  If you want `item` to be able to hold *any* `Number`, you should change

```
 private List<T> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
 private List<Number> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

and `items.add(Integer.valueOf(1))` should work.

On the other hand, if you want to add `1` to `items` as an instance of the runtime type of `T`, that is much more difficult.  The problem is that the code of `MyList` (as written) *does not and cannot know what that type is!*  So, you need to EITHER pass the `T` instance representing `1` as a parameter to `func` OR pass a `Class<T>` parameter to `func` or the constructor and use reflection to create the instance of that class to represent `1`.

But if you want something to *auto-magically* convert the `Integer` to what ever the actual runtime type of `T` is ... that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a so-called [*bounded type parameter*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) `<T extends Number>` means that type `T` is restricted by an upper bound expected to be a `Number` or one of its subtypes.

There are plenty of options if you would think about subtypes of `Number`: `BigDecimal`, `AtomicLong`, etc. That mean that your `List<T>` at runtime might appear to be a `List<AtomicLong>` and since behavior of generic types is invariant we would not be able to add anything that is not of type `AtomicLong` into such list (no `String`s, no `Integer`s, etc.).

Therefore, compiler would disallow to add an `Integer` into a `List<T>`, where `T` can be anything that extends `Number` (or the `Number` itself), because it can't be sure that it's type-safe.